# Start conversation with Wit.ai chat bot in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, chat, chatbot, wit.ai

I have created a story on `wit.ai` using the quickstart guide.

Now I want to make a conversation with my chat bot using `node-wit` in `node.js`.

I guess I should use https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit#runactions to run the messages, but I'm not sure how to start a conversation that never ends. I need to send a message and then get the response from the chat bot until I break the conversation.

I have looked through the `wit.ai` examples, but I cannot find any example of how to start a simple conversation in `node.js`.

I use `socket.io` to transmit the messages between client and server, and I have tried to solve my problem with

```
let sessions = {};
const sessionId = new Date().toISOString();
sessions[sessionId] = { context: {} };

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('new message', function (message) {
    client.runActions(
      sessionId,
      message,
      sessions[sessionId].context
    ).then((context) => {
      console.log(context);
      sessions[sessionId].context = context;
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error('Error: ', err.stack || err);
    });
  });
});
```

and it seems to almost work. I can chat with my bot, but it messes up the stories by sometimes answering multiple times from different stories. I guess I should probably end the stories somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You should try with this link 
https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit/blob/master/examples/quickstart.js

Just clone/download the whole node-wit module from git or **npm-install**.

Then just run the command **node quickstart.js "wit-token"**.

`wit-token == wit-app-token`

it will work .

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this [Facebook Messenger integration example](https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit/blob/master/examples/messenger.js). The quickstart.js includes an interactive mode this is why it may be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the messenger.js example on how to use runActions and send messages back to Messenger.
I was successful in doing this, although I'm still working on stories.

Comment: Do you have an example of your code online somewhere?